# V-lan routing.Need access both vlan from single computer

Tags: vlan, switching

I have  Hp V1910 switch in FIVE different areas. My aim is I want to create a multiple vlan in all switches (means 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.1.2/24).MY aim is to access both vlans in my computer. How it possible? If I do trunk between switch port to my lap.is it work? or please tell me how it possible

Note: No need to communicate both vlans. Only I need access both network in my PC.Is it possible in this HP model Switches? IS work this Scenario?

Comment: those aren't the two vlans are they? (192.168.1.1/24 and 1921.68.1.2/24)?? If so you might want to pick nets like 1.0 and 2.0 /24..

Comment: Please don't suggest to use public IP addresses for local networks. RFC1918 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) was written for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, all modern operating system (I.E. Linux, Windows, MacOS) can handle VLANs.

You will have to create 2 virtual adapter on your computer. The exact method depends of your operating system but a quick internet search will easily lead you to methods to do so.

If you want to retain reliable network (Internet) access you will configure a gateway only on one of this adapter.

Note that configuring PCs is out of scope here, so we will not help you further on this specific task. But if needed you may ask on [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Ok.One more doubt so that port must be trunk ryt? for getting two vlans in PC?

Comment: Right, the port must carry at least one of the 2 vlan as tagged, you could have one vlan as tagged and another one untagged (native vlan) but I don't know if each OS will support this. The simpler is to have both tagged.